# How to get the current effective date in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like the following:

```
TID  TName  EffectiveDate
1    A      2011-7-1
2    A      2011-8-1
3    A      2011-9-1
4    A      2011-10-1
5    B      2011-8-1
6    B      2011-9-1
7    B      2011-10-1
8    C      2011-9-1
```

If today is 2011-9-10, I wish the query result will be like this:

```
TID  TName  EffectiveDate  Status
1    A      2011-7-1       Invalid
2    A      2011-8-1       Invalid
3    A      2011-9-1       Valid
4    A      2011-10-1      Inactive
5    B      2011-8-1       Invalid
6    B      2011-9-1       Valid
7    B      2011-10-1      Inactive
8    C      2011-9-1       Valid
```

If today is 2011-10-2, the query result will be like this:

```
TID  TName  EffectiveDate  Status
1    A      2011-7-1       Invalid
2    A      2011-8-1       Invalid
3    A      2011-9-1       Invalid
4    A      2011-10-1      Valid
5    B      2011-8-1       Invalid
6    B      2011-9-1       Invalid
7    B      2011-10-1      Valid
8    C      2011-9-1       Valid
```

The query result will add one more column named 'Status', and the status value is based on today's value and compare it to the column effectivedate.  The max effective day will be show as 'Valid' Status.  If today’s value is between two record, the latter is 'Inactive' status.

How to write a statement to get this result in oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select TID,
       TName,
       EffectiveDate,
       decode(sign(EffectiveDate - (select max(T2.EffectiveDate) 
                                    from MyTable T2
                                    where T1.Tname=T2.Tname and 
                                          T2.EffectiveDate <= sysdate)),
              -1,'Invalid',
              0,'Valid',
              'Inactive') Status
from MyTable T1
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try, but see for yourself :-)
And with only one table access.

Your table:

```
SQL> create table mytable (tid,tname,effectivedate)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'A', date '2011-07-01' from dual union all
  4  select 2, 'A', date '2011-08-01' from dual union all
  5  select 3, 'A', date '2011-09-01' from dual union all
  6  select 4, 'A', date '2011-10-01' from dual union all
  7  select 5, 'B', date '2011-08-01' from dual union all
  8  select 6, 'B', date '2011-09-01' from dual union all
  9  select 7, 'B', date '2011-10-01' from dual union all
 10  select 8, 'C', date '2011-09-01' from dual
 11  /

Table created.
```

And your two test cases:

```
SQL> var TODAY varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :TODAY := '2011-09-10'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select tid
  2       , tname
  3       , effectivedate
  4       , case
  5         when  to_date(:TODAY,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= effectivedate
  6           and to_date(:TODAY,'yyyy-mm-dd') < next_effectivedate
  7         then
  8           'Valid'
  9         when to_date(:TODAY,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= effectivedate
 10         then
 11           'Invalid'
 12         else
 13           'Inactive'
 14         end status
 15    from ( select tid
 16                , tname
 17                , effectivedate
 18                , lead(effectivedate,1,date '9999-12-31') over (partition by tname order by effectivedate) next_effectivedate
 19             from mytable
 20         )
 21  /

       TID T EFFECTIVEDATE       STATUS
---------- - ------------------- --------
         1 A 01-07-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         2 A 01-08-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         3 A 01-09-2011 00:00:00 Valid
         4 A 01-10-2011 00:00:00 Inactive
         5 B 01-08-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         6 B 01-09-2011 00:00:00 Valid
         7 B 01-10-2011 00:00:00 Inactive
         8 C 01-09-2011 00:00:00 Valid

8 rows selected.

SQL> exec :TODAY := '2011-10-02'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select tid
  2       , tname
  3       , effectivedate
  4       , case
  5         when  to_date(:TODAY,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= effectivedate
  6           and to_date(:TODAY,'yyyy-mm-dd') < next_effectivedate
  7         then
  8           'Valid'
  9         when to_date(:TODAY,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= effectivedate
 10         then
 11           'Invalid'
 12         else
 13           'Inactive'
 14         end status
 15    from ( select tid
 16                , tname
 17                , effectivedate
 18                , lead(effectivedate,1,date '9999-12-31') over (partition by tname order by effectivedate) next_effectivedate
 19             from mytable
 20         )
 21  /

       TID T EFFECTIVEDATE       STATUS
---------- - ------------------- --------
         1 A 01-07-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         2 A 01-08-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         3 A 01-09-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         4 A 01-10-2011 00:00:00 Valid
         5 B 01-08-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         6 B 01-09-2011 00:00:00 Invalid
         7 B 01-10-2011 00:00:00 Valid
         8 C 01-09-2011 00:00:00 Valid

8 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Nice use of analytic function.