# How to write a function to get the current effective date of a row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My Question goes farther then the question in the post below:
[How to get the current effective date in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739602/how-to-get-the-current-effective-date-in-oracle?rq=1)

I have some tables like the example in the post:

```
TID  TName  EffectiveDate   
   1    A      2011-7-1    
   2    A      2011-8-1    
   3    A      2011-9-1
   4    A      2011-10-1    
   5    B      2011-8-1    
   6    B      2011-9-1    
   7    B      2011-10-1    
   8    C      2011-9-1    
   etc...
```

If today is 2011-9-10, I wish the query result will be like this:

```
TID  TName  EffectiveDate  Status    
   1    A      2011-7-1      Invalid    
   2    A      2011-8-1      Invalid    
   3    A      2011-9-1      Valid    
   4    A      2011-10-1     Inactive    
   5    B      2011-8-1      Invalid    
   6    B      2011-9-1      Valid    
   7    B      2011-10-1     Inactive
   8    C      2011-9-1      Valid
```

In the question above there was a solution like this:

```
select TID,
       TName,
       EffectiveDate,
       decode(sign(EffectiveDate - (select max(T2.EffectiveDate) 
                                    from MyTable T2
                                    where T1.Tname=T2.Tname and 
                                          T2.EffectiveDate <= sysdate)),
              -1,'Invalid',
              0,'Valid',
              'Inactive') Status
from MyTable T1
```

and it works fine.

I wanted to **make a function** that you can call with a given table as parameter and that return you the status (valid, invalid or inactive) with the systemdate as default date value.

I don't think it is difficult.

My problem is that sometimes the table contains more columns that you have to take to determine your effective date.

In the example above you only have to look at the TName to take the current effectiveDate.

In the example below you have to take emplid and empl_rcd together

```
TID EMPLID EMPL_RCD EFFECTIVEDATE
1   001    0       2011-07-01
2   001    0       2011-06-25
3   001    1       2011-07-01
4   002    0       2011-07-01
5   002    0       2011-08-01
```

If today is 2012-01-01, the result has to be:

```
TID EMPLID EMPL_RCD EFFECTIVEDATE STATUS
1   001    0       2011-07-01  valid
2   001    0       2011-06-25  invalid
3   001    1       2011-07-01  valid
4   002    0       2011-07-01  invalid
5   002    0       2011-08-01  valid
```

In my second example my query should be like

```
select TID,
       TName,
       EffectiveDate,
       decode(sign(EffectiveDate - (select max(T2.EffectiveDate) 
                                    from MyTable T2
                                    where **T1.emplid=T2.emplid and
                                          T1.empl_rcd = T2.empl_rcd and** 
                                          T2.EffectiveDate <= sysdate)),
              -1,'Invalid',
              0,'Valid',
              'Inactive') Status
from MyTable T1
```

But I want a function that you can call like for example

```
select T1.*,effdt_status(mytable) as status from mytable
```

That return me the status of that row. But like a mention in the two different example, sometimes more columns has to be grouped to determine the effectiveDate.

Can anyone help me to write that function?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select t.*,
       (case sum(case when tdate <= date '2011-09-10' then 1 else 0 end)  over (partition by tname order by tdate desc)
            when 0 then 'Inactive'
            when 1 then 'Valid'
            else 'Invalid'
        end)
from mytable t;
```

This should assign `'Inactive'` to any future date, `'Valid'` to the most recent date, and `'Invalid'` to past ones.

You can also express this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when tdate > date '2011-09-10' then 'Inactive'
             when not exists (select 1
                              from mytable t2
                              where t2.tname = t.tname and 
                                    t2.tdate > t.tdate and 
                                    t2.tdate <= date '2011-09-10'
                             )
             then 'Valid'
             else 'Invalid'
        end)
from mytable t;
```

Comment: no that is nog what I meant. I edited my question to be more clear. I want a function to be able to do select T1.*,effdt_status(mytable) as status from mytable and the function return me the status (valid,invalid or inactive)